# Current logged user in tag helper

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

Using asp.net core, is it possible to get the current logged user in a tag helper class?

lets suppose this tag helper:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("lesson")]
public class LessonTagHelper : BaseTagHelper
{
    private readonly ILessonServices lessonService;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;

    public LessonTagHelper(ILessonServices lessonService, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        this.lessonService = lessonService;
        this.userManager = userManager;
    }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {            
        base.Process(context, output);
        output.TagName = "div";

        *** I NEED USER HERE ***
```

I know that in the controller we have a "User" property ready to use, but it is not available in other classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inject `IHttpContextAccessor` into LessonTagHelper

```
private readonly ILessonServices lessonService;
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

public LessonTagHelper(ILessonServices lessonService, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
        this.lessonService = lessonService;
        this.userManager = userManager;
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}
```

and then where you need you can access User like `httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User` ...

Do not forget that [IHttpContextAccessor service is not registered by default](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/190), so

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```